# Как запретить удаление приложения в Android?

Tags: java, android

Хочу узнать если способ сделать запрет на удаление моего приложения из Android.

Т.е я установил его, когда буду заходить в Настройки-> Приложения -> Мое приложение, кнопка "удалить" была не не активна или вообще скрыть моё приложение в разделе "Приложения".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

никак.
разве что можно сделать свою собственную прошивку, включив приложение в нее в качестве системного. тогда удалить будет нельзя, и то при условии что телефон без рута.

Comment: Я так и думал. Что только можно сделать как системное и засунуть в прошивку. А можно ли сделать, чтобы приложение запускалось само,после его отключения.

Comment: в принципе с помощью AlarmManager это можно сделать
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17166729/1233682

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать автозапуск приоожения после его завершения, то попробуйте что-нибудь придумать с сервисом. Ведь при его аварийном завершении он сам перезапустится в течении 10 секунд. Поэтому попробуйте сделать код в сервисе, который будет запускать основную активити, если она завершена.

Насчёт неудаляемости: запросите рут, а потом просто скопируте /data/app/приложение в /system/app/.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал использовать для этих целей BroadcastReceaver, а не service